# cannot resolve R when applying BottomNavigationView bottombar

Tags: android

when I add bottomNavigationView, I got cannot resolve R , but when I remove the bottomNavigationView the error disappear, so why I am getting such error ?

the below code result to unresolved `R`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.learn2crack.recyclerviewgrid.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
        app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

when remove it as the below the error disappear

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.learn2crack.recyclerviewgrid.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/card_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your XML's contain errors your generated file might not build try erasing most of their content and making sure id's are not duplicated.

Check if you have imported the right lib to work with BottomNavigation and none of your props are null.

Here is my Activity code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/activity_main"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context="MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_menu_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_menu_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />

<ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"/>
```